# Unsatisfiable Monotone $(3^+, 2^{- })$ SAT example request

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

Monotone $(3^+, 2^-)$ SAT can be defined as follows:

Given a monotone CNF formula $(+F^3, -F^2)$, each positive monotone clause of length 3 and each negative monotone clause of length 2.

Each variable appears exactly once (as a positive literal in clauses in $+F^3$), (on the same variables as in $+F^3$) and one or more times in $-F^2$, (where all variables are negated).

Is $(+F^3, -F^2)$ satisfiable?

The above problem is NP-Complete (ref: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16634/complexity-of-monotone-2-sat-problem)

Can someone provide with a small non trivial instance of this problem that are unsatisfiable?

Comment: can someone please explain the negative voting. I thought this was a valid question on a generic mathematics forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

$(X \vee Y \vee Z) \land (A \vee B \vee C) \land $

$(\neg A \vee \neg X) \land (\neg A \vee \neg Y) \land (\neg A \vee \neg Z) \land$

$(\neg B \vee \neg X) \land (\neg B \vee \neg Y) \land (\neg B \vee \neg Z) \land$

$(\neg C \vee \neg X) \land (\neg C \vee \neg Y) \land (\neg C \vee \neg Z)$

It's supposed to say that at least one of $X, Y, Z$ is true, and that at least one of $A, B, C$ is true, but also that any pair of variables chosen from each triple cannot both be true.

Comment: Much thanks. It seems perfect.

Comment: You can omit the first six 2-clauses.

Comment: simplified .....